# align content at bottom of columns

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm managing a trivial column-splitted section in my website to show the abstract of some content. Each column has got a link at the end. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/CV4Yr/2.

The problem is: how can I align those read-more link at the bottom of the section so that all three of the read-more links line up horizontally? Notice that columns seem to have equal height, but it's just a trick using negative margin.

Of course I can imagine a lot of javascript hacks, but I'd rather avoid them.

Thanks

EDIT: I corrected the link to the right version of the fiddle. Now columns are equal heighted.

Comment: so the thing is. you have to set those contents to the bottom of the page?

Comment: They're not equal height in FF13. FYI.

Comment: Here is what I see: http://i.imgur.com/MP4e1.png (Chrome 20b)

Comment: hey @balanza i you want this http://jsfiddle.net/CV4Yr/12/

Comment: yes i think Rohit Azad his answer is right?

Comment: @RohitAzad That wasn't the solution, but I used to find my way. Check the answer

Comment: here a fiddle showing the correct result. I achived it displaying articles as 'table-cell'. Do you think it's correct, or exists a better way? http://jsfiddle.net/CV4Yr/13/

Comment: @PatsyIssa as soon I'll get answered, I'll do it. it's boyscout promise.

Comment: no, because equal height is still achived by playing with background and/or padding. meanwhile, content area is still in the same size, so no way to say the <a> to look at the wrapper and not at its parent

Answer (score 0):

Because of the method you've used to make the columns an equal height, placing a link at the bottom is going to be difficult.

If you can find an alternative method, something as simple as this would work added into your existing code:

```
article {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

article > a {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; left: 0;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: But how I get column to be equal eighted?

Comment: Here a couple of links to the methods available: http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/ http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks